# groupId not defined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating chrome extension that will group tabs based on their domains and if a tab already has a group based on their domain, it will avoid creating a new group and just append the tab to the existing group. To do this I am creating a const variable called existing group, where if the tab's group id is not negative (meaning it has a group) and the group key matches the domain of the tab, it will store it as an existing group. But unfoortunately, when it tries to find the groupId, it says groupId not defined and so, even if the tab is existing in a group, it doesn't get added as an existing group and the function goes on to regroup all the tabs. I am fairly new to javascrip, so I am a bit of confused as in how to solve this. Please help me understand what I am doing wrong and how to resolve the problem. This is also my first post to the slack overflow, so if I amade a mistale point me to the right direction. The code I am writing is given bellow:

I have followed the chrome api docs and I feel like I am following using the reference as they have instructed there. But still I am getting the error. I have also checked the permissions, and the permissions are given in the menifest.json.

```
// Wait for the DOM content to be fully loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  // Add an event listener to the "Group Tabs" button
  document.getElementById("groupTabsButton").addEventListener("click", groupOrAppendTabs);

  // Automatically group tabs when the popup is opened
  groupOrAppendTabs();
});

// Function to group tabs based on domain names or append to existing groups
function groupOrAppendTabs() {
  // Query the currently open tabs in the current window
  chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    const tabGroups = {};

    // Iterate through each tab
    tabs.forEach(function (tab) {
      const tabDomain = new URL(tab.url).hostname; // Get the domain name
      console.log('tabDomain', tabDomain);

      if (!tabGroups[tabDomain]) {
        tabGroups[tabDomain] = [tab];
      } else {
        console.log('tab group already exists');
        tabGroups[tabDomain].push(tab);
      }
    });

    // Iterate through the grouped tabs
    for (const [groupKey, groupTabs] of Object.entries(tabGroups)) {
      //console.log('groupID: ', groupId)
      
      if (groupTabs.length > 1) {
        const tabIds = Tabs.map(tab => tab.id);
        console.log('tab id: ', tabIds);
        console.log('Group Key: ', groupKey);
        
        //console.log('title: ', title);

        // Find existing group with matching title (domain)
        const existingGroup = tabs.find(tab => tab.groupId !== -1 && tab.title === groupKey);
        console.log('Existing Group:', existingGroup);
        console.log('Group Id: ', groupId);


        if (existingGroup) {
          // Append ungrouped tabs with the same domain to the existing group
          const ungroupedTabs = tabs.filter(tab => tab.groupId === -1 && new URL(tab.url).hostname === groupKey);
          const ungroupedTabIds = ungroupedTabs.map(tab => tab.id);
          console.log(`Tab (ID: ${tab.id}) added to the existing group for domain: ${groupKey}`);

          if (ungroupedTabIds.length > 0) {
            chrome.tabs.group({ tabIds: ungroupedTabIds, groupId: existingGroup.groupId }, function () {
              // Ungrouped tabs added to the existing group
            });
          }
        } else {
          // Group the tabs using chrome.tabs.group API
          chrome.tabs.group({ tabIds: tabIds }, function (groupId) {
            console.log('Tabs grouped with groupId:', groupId);
            // Once grouped, update the title using chrome.tabGroups API
            chrome.tabGroups.update(groupId, { title: groupKey }, function (updatedGroup) {
              // Tab group title updated
              console.log('regrouped successfully');
            });
          });
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: You don't have a variable named `groupId`. It's a property of an object so it'd be something like `existingGroup?.groupId`